# objective-c how to us NSURLSession with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have this code here that logins me into a URL, my issue is when I try to remove the creds it was not working, but I found a solution online:

http://www.ciiycode.com/0yHHmeXWgUqQ/using-nsurlcredentialpersistenceforsession-while-request-and-then-clearing-the-credentials-on-logout-still-persist-the-cerdentials

```
If you're using NSURLSession, invalidate the session and create a new one, e.g.:

[self.session invalidateAndCancel];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
This will clear session-scoped credentials.
```

so my question is, can I use NSURLSession with AFNetworking:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:request];

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:user
                                   password:password
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    [operation setCredential:credential];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];


    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(nil, error);
        }

    }];

    [operation start];
```

**UPDATE**

I got started on this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kIP];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
        }
    }] resume];
```

how do I add a username and password to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using AFNSURLSession instead of AFHTTPRequestOperation. In AFNSURLSession you can supply a block to the delegate setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock where you can provide the necessary credential.

From AFNSURLSession.h:

```
/**
 Sets a block to be executed when a connection level authentication challenge has occurred, as handled by the `NSURLSessionDelegate` method `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:`.
 @param block A block object to be executed when a connection level authentication challenge has occurred. The block returns the disposition of the authentication challenge, and takes three arguments: the session, the authentication challenge, and a pointer to the credential that should be used to resolve the challenge.
 */
- (void)setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition (^)(NSURLSession *session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge, NSURLCredential * __autoreleasing *credential))block;
```

Comment: I updated my question with that I got I just need to know how add a username and password